# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{[x]+[3^2x]+\dots+[(2n-1)^2x]}{n^3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate
>   $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{[x]+[3^2x]+\dots+[(2n-1)^2x]}{n^3}$$ where $[x]$, $[3^2x]$, $[(2n-1)^2x]$ are the floor functions (the greatest integer function). I think i managed to solve this one, i just want to double-check with you . So, i' ve started like this:

$x-1<[x]\le x$

$3^2x-1<[3^2x]\le 3^2x$

.....................

$(2n-1)^2x-1<[(2n-1)^2x]\le (2n-1)^2x$   =>(i added them all together) 
$[1^2+3^2+....+(2n-1)^2]x-n < [x]+ [3^2x]+....+[(2n-1)^2x]\le [1^2+3^2+....+(2n-1)^2]x$ 
=>( i amplified with $\frac{1}{n^3}$) and i've applied the squeeze theorem with gave me the solution : $\frac{x}{2}$

Comment: Your approach is the right one. Can you derive a formula for the sum $1^2+3^2+\cdots+(2n-1)^2$? That's what it boils down to.

Comment: I wrote it like this : $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}2k^2$ . Is this correct ?

Comment: Not quite. It's $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)^2$. But the question is what the sum is equal to.

Comment: I think i got it : $\frac{2n(n+1)(2n+1)-6n(n+1)+3n}{3}$

Comment: Is this correct ?

Comment: It looks correct. From that, you should be able to compute the limit (divide by $n^3$).

Comment: So, the answer is : $ 4\frac{x}{3}$

Comment: Yep, got it now . Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Stolz theorem
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{[x]+[3^2x]+\dots+[(2n-1)^2x]}{n^3}\\
&=&\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n[(2k-1)^2x]}{n^3}\\
&=&\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}[(2k-1)^2x]-\sum_{k=1}^n[(2k-1)^2x]}{n^3}\\
&=&\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{[(2n+1)^2x]}{(n+1)^3-n^3}\\
&=&\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{[(2n+1)^2x]}{3n^2+3n+1}\\
&=&\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{[(2n+1)^2x]}{(2n+1)^2}\cdot\frac{(2n+1)^2}{3n^2+3n+1}\\
&=&\frac{4x}{3}.
\end{eqnarray}
Here
$$ \frac{[nx]}{n}=x $$
is used.

Answer (score 1):

More generally,
if $m \ge 1$,
$h(x) > 0$,
and
$f_m(n, x)
=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n [h(x)(2k-1)^m]}{n^{m+1}}
$
and
$g_m(n, x)
=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n h(x)(2k-1)^m}{n^{m+1}}
$
then
$0
\le g_m(n, x)-f_m(n, x)
\le 
\dfrac1{n^m}
$

so doing integer part
does not change the limit.

If
$s_m(n)
=\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^m
$
and
$t_m(n)
=\sum_{k=1}^n k^m
$
then

$\begin{array}\\
s_m(n)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^m\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n ((2k-1)^m+(2k)^m-(2k)^m)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n ((2k-1)^m+(2k)^m)-\sum_{k=1}^n (2k)^m\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} k^m-2^m\sum_{k=1}^n k^m\\
&=t_{m}(2n)-2^{m}t_m(n)\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$t_m(n)
=\dfrac{n^{m+1}}{m+1}+\dfrac{n^m}{2}+O(n^{m-1})
$,

$\begin{array}\\
s_m(n)
&=t_{m}(2n)-2^{m}t_m(n)\\
&=\dfrac{(2n)^{m+1}}{m+1}+\dfrac{(2n)^m}{2}+O(n^{m-1})-2^{m}(\dfrac{n^{m+1}}{m+1}+\dfrac{n^m}{2}+O(n^{m-1}))\\
&=\dfrac{2^{m+1}n^{m+1}}{m+1}+\dfrac{2^mn^m}{2}-2^{m}\dfrac{n^{m+1}}{m+1}-2^{m}\dfrac{n^m}{2}+O(n^{m-1})\\
&=\dfrac{2^{m}n^{m+1}}{m+1}+O(n^{m-1})\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{s_m(n)}{n^{m+1}}
&=\dfrac{2^{m}}{m+1}+O(\dfrac1{n^2})\\
\end{array}
$

For $m=2$ this is
$\dfrac{s_2(n)}{n^{3}}
=\dfrac{4}{3}+O(\dfrac1{n^2})
$
so the result is
$\dfrac{4x}{3}
$.

Note:

All that is needed is
$t_m(n)
=\dfrac{n^{m+1}}{m+1}+O(n^{m})
$,
and this can be derived from
the approximation
$t_m(n)
\approx \int_0^n x^m dx
$.

For $m=2$,
of course,
we have the explicit formula
$t_2(n)
=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$.